# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'copy' error when moved the function Select to a common file using Selenium Python through Django

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a HTML element like this

```html
<select id="my_id">
<option value="">ALL</option>
<option value="1.0">ALL</option>
<option value="2.0">A</option>
<option value="3.0">B</option>
<option value="4.0">C</option>
</select>
```

I want to select and choose an value of that, when I use define a function in test file
It will working OK

```py
my_test_file.py
def _find_and_select(self, elm_id, value):
    select_item = Select(self.browser.find_element_by_id(elm_id))
    select_item.select_by_value(value)
```

```py
self._find_and_select("my_id", "1.0")
```

But when I move to a common test file

```py
common_file.py
class Common:
    @staticmethod
    def _find_and_select(browser, elm_id, value):
        select_item = Select(browser.find_element_by_id(elm_id))
        select_item.select_by_value(value)
```

```py
my_test_file.py
Common._find_and_select(self.browser, "my_id", "1.0")
```

It's will get error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\iBNet-Prj\ibnet\apps\autotest\contract\tests.py", line 251, in test_search
    CommonTest._find_and_select(self.browser, "contractLoanStatus", loanStatus[0])
  File "D:\iBNet-Prj\ibnet\apps\common_test.py", line 467, in _find_and_select
    select_item = Select(browser.find_element_by_id(elm_id))
  File "D:\iBNet-Prj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 558, in __init__
    super().__init__(attrs)
  File "D:\iBNet-Prj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 201, in __init__
    self.attrs = {} if attrs is None else attrs.copy()
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
  File "D:\iBNet-Prj\ibnet\apps\common_test.py", line 467, in _find_and_select
    select_item = Select(browser.find_element_by_id(elm_id))
  File "D:\iBNet-Prj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 558, in __init__
    super().__init__(attrs)
  File "D:\iBNet-Prj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 201, in __init__
    self.attrs = {} if attrs is None else attrs.copy()
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

...implies that the line of code `select_item = Select(browser.find_element_by_id(elm_id))` failed and as you are using [django](/questions/tagged/django) framework `super().__init__(attrs)` was invoked which produces the error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

### Solution

To select the desired element ideally you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  select_item = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#my_id"))))
  select_item.select_by_value(value)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  select_item = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='my_id']"))))
  select_item.select_by_value(value)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks you so much, I will try it

Comment: Nice explanation